# Dojo: How to load an object (containing other objects) from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, dojo, deserialization

I have an object model that I want to be able to save.  I am going to export it to JSON and then read it back in as JSON.

Saving to JSON is easy.  Just use this: `JSON.stringify(this)`.

Loading from JSON isn't as simple.

- We can't just use `this = JSON.parse(someJson)` because the methods wont be attached.
- Using something like `lang.mixin(this, JSON.parse(someJson))` will get the functions but objects that are

Photo Class:

```
define([...], function(...){
    return declare(null, {
        name: ..., // String
        url:..., // String
        complexProperty:..., // Some other class

        someFunction1: function(...){..},
        someFunction2: function(...){..},
        someFunction2: function(...){..}
    }
));
```

Photo Album Class:

```
define([...], function(...){
    return declare(null, {
        photos: [], /* Array of type Photo (see above) */
        someOtherProperty: ...,
        someOtherProperty: ...,

        someFunction1: function(...){..},
        someFunction2: function(...){..},
        someFunction2: function(...){..},

        toJson: function(){
            return JSON.stringify(this);    // From dojo/json
        }

        loadFromJson: function(jsonIn){
            // How to do this?
        }, 

        /* This doesn't work because methods will be overridden */
        loadFromJson1: function(jsonIn){
            this = JSON.parse(someJson);
        }, 

        /* This insures that my methods are kept intact but my childrens methods arn't (ie: the array of photos) */
        loadFromJson2: function(jsonIn){
            lang.mixin(this, JSON.parse(someJson));
        }, 

        /* This seems like an aweful lot of work.  Any better ways to do this? */
        loadFromJson3: function(jsonIn){
            this.someOtherProperty = jsonIn.someOtherProperty;
            this.someOtherProperty = jsonIn.someOtherProperty;
            foreach(jsonIn.photos: photoJson){
                var newPhoto = new Photo();
                newPhoto.loadfromJson(photoJson);
                this.photos.add(newPhoto);
            }
            ... All other properties set recursively.  All things in model now need this method ...
        }
    }
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would be better off returning a JSON object that contains just the data you need to serialize, not the whole class. Then your loadFromJson method would be a little easier to implement, and you wont be sending unnecessary data over the network. Example toJson():

```
toJson: function() {
    return JSON.stringify({
        photos: this.photos,
        someImportantProp: this.someImportantProp,
        anotherProp: this.anotherProp
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is not the same thing as a JavaScript object, in fact, it's only a subset. JSON only allows arrays, objects and of course basic types like Strings, booleans, numbers and `null`. You can find the entire specification [here](http://json.org/).

If you really want to keep the functions you can use the `eval()` function, but this is not really recommended, because it indeed parses those functions. If the evaluated content contains malicious input, then that is being executed as well.

For example:

```
eval("myObj = { getSum: function getSum(a, b) { return a + b; } }");
myObj.getSum(1, 2); // Returns 3
```

You can better attempt to save the **state** of the object (`name` and `url` for example) and rebuild it once you parse it again, that is what happens in other programming languages as well. For example, if you're serializing/deserializing an object in Java.